# Regex match exactly 1 anywhere in string

Tags: regex

So I need to match upper and lower case a-z letters, period (.) and @ in a string. As a complication the string must have @ exactly once anywhere in the string and . at least once anywhere in the string.

```
abcd@.  // match
@ab.cd  // match
a@cd@.  // no match
abcd@  // no match
```

I've tried to be clever (obviously not very) by doing look ahead but this one seems tricky eg.

```
(?=[@]){1}[a-zA-Z@]+$
```

Comment: Yes, it must be `^(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)[a-zA-Z@.]+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnLI2e/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?=[@]){1}[a-zA-Z@]+$` pattern matches any substring that starts with `@` and then has zero or more letters or `@` up to the end of the string. Look at [what it matches](https://regex101.com/r/fnLI2e/2).

You need to use

```
^(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)(?=[^.]*\.)[a-zA-Z@.]+$
```

Or, if there must be also one dot (and no more than one) in the string

```
^(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)[a-zA-Z@.]+$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/fnLI2e/3) and the [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/fnLI2e/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)` - **requires only one `@` and no more than one in string** - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ chars other than `@`, a `@`, and again zero or more chars other than `@` till the end of string
- `(?=[^.]*\.)` - **requires at least one dot** - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ chars other than `.` and then a `.`
- `(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)` - **requires only one dot and no more than one in string** - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ chars other than `.`, a `.`, and again zero or more chars other than `.` till the end of string
- `[a-zA-Z@.]+` - one or more ASCII letters, `@` or `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could just use:

```
^(?=.*\.)[a-zA-Z.]*@[a-zA-Z.]*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kgw3QQ/3).

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?=.*.)` - Positive lookahead for any amount of characters up to a literal dot.
- `[a-zA-Z.]*` - Zero or more characters from upper/lowercase letters or a dot.
- `@` - A single `@`.
- `[a-zA-Z.]*` - Zero or more characters from upper/lowercase letters or a dot.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using a single lookahead asserting `@` and match a dot between 2 character classes, or the other way around asserting a dot and matching `@`

```
^(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)[A-Za-z@]*\.[A-Za-z@]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)` Assert only 1 @ char in the string
- `[A-Za-z@]*\.[A-Za-z@]*` Match a dot between optionally repeating character classes each matching 1 out of A-Za-z@
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eqlHlA/1)

For *and . at least once anywhere in the string* , you can allow matching a dot in the second character class:

```
^(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$)[A-Za-z@]*\.[A-Za-z@.]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NN9jAK/1)

Comment: @JvdV I did check it +1 It asserts a dot and matches an @ between chars `a-zA-Z.` There is a part in the question about at least a single dot,so IMHO it looks ok.